# imap google with php: couldn't open stream

Tags: php, imap

I'm trying to get emails through a PHP script:

```
$mbox = imap_open("{imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl/novalidate-cert}INBOX", "username@gmail.com", "password");
```

But I'm constantly getting this error:

> Warning: imap_open(): Couldn't open stream {imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl/novalidate-cert}INBOX

IMap is enabled on my Google Account.
From the server, I tried `nmap -p 993 imap.gmail.com` and it return that there is imap service under this address.

regards

Comment: Did you make sure that you allow Less Secure Apps to access your gmail account?

Comment: Yes I'm sure...

Comment: novalidate-cert may not be required tried removing it?

Answer (score 0):

In my case, this error is caused by the outbound proxy blocking access to port 993.